# Translate integers in a numpy array to a contiguous range 0...n

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to translate arbitrary integers in a numpy array to a contiguous range 0...n, like this:

```
source: [2 3 4 5 4 3]
translating [2 3 4 5] -> [0 1 2 3]
target: [0 1 2 3 2 1]
```

There must be a better way to than the following:

```
import numpy as np

"translate arbitrary integers in the source array to contiguous range 0...n"

def translate_ids(source, source_ids, target_ids):
    target = source.copy()

    for i in range(len(source_ids)):
        x = source_ids[i]
        x_i = source == x
        target[x_i] = target_ids[i]

    return target

#

source = np.array([ 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3 ])
source_ids = np.unique(source)
target_ids = np.arange(len(source_ids))

target = translate_ids(source, source_ids, target_ids)

print "source:", source
print "translating", source_ids, '->', target_ids
print "target:", target
```

What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can simply use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)'s optional argument `return_inverse`, like so -

```
np.unique(source,return_inverse=True)[1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: source
Out[44]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3])

In [45]: np.unique(source,return_inverse=True)[1]
Out[45]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: It would be nice to point out whether this preserves the property of order. For example: does a value of zero keep its value?

Comment: @RadioControlled It maps min to max onto 0..n seq. So, if 0 is the min element, then it stays as 0.

Comment: What about the other elements? Do they keep their order? `np.argsort(source)==np.argsort(np.unique(source,return_inverse=True)[1])` for all `source`?

Comment: @RadioControlled Yes.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) is one method:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3]
res = pd.factorize(lst, sort=True)[0]

# [0 1 2 3 2 1]
```

**Note**: this returns a list, while `np.unique` will always return an `np.ndarray`.